# MVC Attribute Routing - Default Controller Index with GET and POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1, attributerouting

We have an MVC 5.1 project and are using attribute routing. Everything is working fine except the default page which has a login form on it.

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")] 
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [Route("~/")]
    [Route]
    [Route("Index")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new LoginViewModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(String Username, String Password)
```

The form is displayed via the GET fine but upon the POST we get...

**HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**

The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Normally the default route would handle both the POST and GET fine.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{dealerId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Obviously I am missing something here on the routing for the post on the default route as subsequent posts on other pages work fine.

Has anyone done this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok seems all I have to do is add

```
 [Route("~/")]
 [Route]
 [Route("Index")]
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

 public ActionResult Index(String Username, String Password)
```

Obvious really! Long Day!